# BTEQ script: Error while copying a table into another one

Tags: scripting, teradata, sql-insert

I want to copy the content of a temporary table (named in my script DLM_PE_TEMPO) into another one (DLM_PE) withe the following BTEQ script:

```
  INSERT INTO DLM_PE 
(
   TSTAMP , 

   Line_ID ,

   Key_Date , 

   DS_SYNCH_RATE ,

   Us_Synch_Rate , 

   Ds_Cv_X1_Percentile , 

   Ds_Cv_X2_Percentile , 

   Us_Cv_X1_Percentile , 

   Us_Cv_X2_Percentile , 

   Stability , 

   Systemtype 

)

SELECT 

  :TSTAMP (date) , 

  :Line_ID (varchar(10)), 

  :Key_Date (date), 

  :DS_SYNCH_RATE (float), 

  :Us_Synch_Rate (float) ,

  :Ds_Cv_X1_Percentile (float) , 

  :Ds_Cv_X2_Percentile (float) ,  

  :Us_Cv_X1_Percentile (float) , 

  :Us_Cv_X2_Percentile (float) , 

  :Stability (integer) , 

  :Systemtype (integer) 

FROM DLM_PE_TEMPO ;
```

But each time it fails and I get the following error:

```
Failure 3857 Cannot use value (or macro parameter) to match 'TSTAMP'.
                Statement# 1, Info =0
```

Could you please tell me what is the problem with my BTEQ script? Am I doing the INSERT statement wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There's no import, you don't have a USING. So no colon in front of the column name:

```
  INSERT INTO DLM_PE 
(
   TSTAMP , 
   Line_ID ,
   Key_Date , 
   DS_SYNCH_RATE ,
   Us_Synch_Rate , 
   Ds_Cv_X1_Percentile , 
   Ds_Cv_X2_Percentile , 
   Us_Cv_X1_Percentile , 
   Us_Cv_X2_Percentile , 
   Stability , 
   Systemtype 
)
SELECT 
  TSTAMP (date) , 
  Line_ID (varchar(10)), 
  Key_Date (date), 
  DS_SYNCH_RATE (float), 
  Us_Synch_Rate (float) ,
  Ds_Cv_X1_Percentile (float) , 
  Ds_Cv_X2_Percentile (float) ,  
  Us_Cv_X1_Percentile (float) , 
  Us_Cv_X2_Percentile (float) , 
  Stability (integer) , 
  Systemtype (integer) 
FROM DLM_PE_TEMPO ;
```

And you don't need those typecasts (unless you must add a specific FORMAT), if the data taypes don't match there will be an automatic cast:

```
  INSERT INTO DLM_PE 
(
   TSTAMP , 
   Line_ID ,
   Key_Date , 
   DS_SYNCH_RATE ,
   Us_Synch_Rate , 
   Ds_Cv_X1_Percentile , 
   Ds_Cv_X2_Percentile , 
   Us_Cv_X1_Percentile , 
   Us_Cv_X2_Percentile , 
   Stability , 
   Systemtype 
)
SELECT 
  TSTAMP , 
  Line_ID , 
  Key_Date , 
  DS_SYNCH_RATE , 
  Us_Synch_Rate ,
  Ds_Cv_X1_Percentile , 
  Ds_Cv_X2_Percentile ,  
  Us_Cv_X1_Percentile , 
  Us_Cv_X2_Percentile , 
  Stability , 
  Systemtype
FROM DLM_PE_TEMPO ;
```